# Error while running unity_support_test

Tags: unity, 12.04

My unity session won't start and it always gives me a segmentation fault. So I tried running /usr/lib/unity_support_test but this too gave me some error.

> X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
>
> Serial number of failed request:  22
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  22

What does this mean? Doesn't my machine satisfy unity's requirements?

Comment: What is your graphics card i.e. `lspci | grep VGA` ?  Please add this to your question.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix myself for this. It was a problem due to fglrx drivers. I purged those drivers from my system and installed open source drivers for my graphics chipset. For people facing the same problem you can visit this link [here](http://nerdysermons.blogspot.in/2011/11/solve-graphic-driver-errors-unity-3d.html)

Answer (score 0):

What does this mean? = It FAILED

Doesn't my machine satisfy unity's requirements? = NO

You may try running Unity 2D instead or Gnome Fallback or upgrade your graphics card.

The other option is to run Live CD and perform the same test to find if it fails again. It may be a hardware driver issue.

BTW at least 3 bugs reported on Mobile 4 Series Chipset and Error while running unity_support_test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do newer versions of unity run on computer with a Mobile 4 Series chipset?

Comment: I also have problem with my alt-tab switcher. I get the old gnome alt-tab switcher and not the new one where windows of same application are grouped together. How can I get the latest alt-tab switcher?